# How to pass data to a PHP file, run in new window

Tags: php, ajax, dompdf

I'm trying to run DOMPDF on a button click. I have a pdftest.php file:

```
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$filename = "pagetopdf.html";
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml(file_get_contents($filename));
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("testfile");
```

If I just load this file, it works fine.

However, I want to pass the filename I want to pdf through to it, and then run the PHP.

So I change the third line above to:

```
$filename=$_POST["mydata"];
```

And I have a button in a HTML file, with an AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({url: "pdftest.php", type:"POST", data:{'mydata': "pagetopdf.html"}, data success: function(result){
        .....
      }});
   });
});
```

... but I have no idea what to put for the result. If I open a new window and write pdftest.php to it, DOMPDF outputs to the window, not into a PDF file. How can I pass through data and run the PHP file? Thanks!

Comment: use `window.open('pdftest.php?mydata=filename','_blank')` and replace `$_POST` with `$_GET` in your php. Also sanitize the `$filename`. It would be possible to call `pdftest.php?mydata=../../../../etc/passwd` and obtain the server passwords under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'r almost there. May be your are missing the base path when ajax requests.

Try this!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("button").click(function(){
          var base_url = 'your server root';
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: base_url + "pdftest.php",
                data:{'mydata': "pagetopdf.html"},
                success: function(response) { 
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(response) {                      
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
       });
    });
```